# How to architect this kind of project?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, user-interface

To say I have two classes:

```
 ClassA{
    //properties 
    public string NAME{set;get;}
    public string ID{set;get;}
    public int AGE{set;get;}
    //Methods
    public void DoSomething();
    public void MethodA();
    private void MethodB(string name);
    private void MethodC(string name);
    public void MethodD(string name,string id);
    public string getSomething(int age);
    }

    ClassB{
    public void Hello(int input);
    public void HelloWorld(string input);
    }
```

1) For ClassA(may have many derived classes),what is the best way to create a design interface(GUI) so that I can specify its property value

2) For ClassA, is there a way to create a design interface(GUI) so that I can specify which method to call and  specify the sequence/input/output of methods called?

```
    public void DoSomethingWithClassA(ClassA ca ){
    ca.MethodA();
  //  ca.MethodB(ca.NAME);
  //  ca.MethodB(ca.ID);
    ca.MethodD(ca.NAME,getSomthing(ca.AGE));

    }
```

3) If I have an instance of ClassA, named newClassA, an instance of ClassB, named newClassB, is there a way to create a design interface(GUI) so that I can specify that newClassB could invoke newClassA's method:

```
ClassA newClassA...
ClassB newClassB...

newClassB.HelloWorld(newClassA.getSomething(newClassA.AGE));
```

Basically what I need is to have a design interface(GUI) so that user could "visually design" his classes and could specify relation/input/output of method. I feel it's something like filter graph.

If someone could possible figure out a solution/framework/design pattern/keywords, it would be much appreciated.

(I should highlight that design interface means GUI for user, sorry for that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like fluent interfaces.

Take a look at this article, it should help you on how to implement this: http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2010/06/26/how-to-write-fluent-interface-with-c-and-lambda.aspx

Here's a quick example on how you can use this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    internal Person { }
}

public class PersonFactory
{
    public NameSetter CreatePerson()
    {
        return new NameSetter(new Person());
    }
}

public class NameSetter
{
    private Person person;

    internal NameSetter(Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public AgeSetter SetName(string name)
    {
        this.person.Name = name;
        return new AgeSetter(this.person);
    }
}

public class AgeSetter
{
    private Person person;

    internal AgeSetter(Person person)
    {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public Person SetAge(int age)
    {
        this.person.Age = age;
        return this.person;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        Person p = new PersonFactory()
                       .CreatePerson()
                       .SetName("Bob")
                       .SetAge(30);
    }
}
```

I updated the example to make the constructor of `Person` internal. It's not mandatory but if you do so, it will force any user of your code to use the fluent interface to create an instance of a `Person`.

Comment: I found this video (outlining the design of fluent validation) very helpful on this topic: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/13/fluentvalidation-c4mvc-video/

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will check it out.

Comment: Hi, Guillaume and DanP, I am sorry that I didn't make my point clear enough ,my design interface means a GUI for user. But still thanks for your information :)

Comment: Well, even if it's for a UI I think it can still work. Just replace `PersonFactory` by some kind of `UIDesigner` that creates instances of some objects handling UI creation. Instead of having a `NameSetter` you have a `ComboboxDesigner` for example. You can also add more than one parameter to the methods if need be.